# CSS: Center Center Alignment and have Div to hide overflowing images

Tags: html, css, overflow, center

I was able to set my divs and images to center center (center horizontal, center vertical) alignment using CSS:

```css
.center {
  height: 100%
}

.center-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999999
}

.image{
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class =" center-center ">
    <img class="image" src="http://kb4images.com/images/picture/37509081-picture.jpg" />
    <img class ="overlay " src="http://makephotogreetings.com/upload/1456330147Happy%20Birthday%20Frame%20With%20Cup%20Cake%20and%20Your%20Photo.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, my problem is that even I set overflow:hidden in class "center-center" it will hide some parts, but one side is still showing. I tried to assign a height for the frame image, but it will affect the positioning since. Does anyone know if this is possible?

*I have updated the snippet and the code for better understanding*

Comment: use real image so we can see

Comment: hmm, what real image? that's the real image of the UI im working

Comment: when you run the snippet your created here, you see images ? .. me i see nothing

Comment: oh, i mean the screenshot. yes, the snippent wont work. the path or the image is different

Comment: `the snippent wont work. the path or the image is different` --> you got it then ! so how you want us to help you if we are no able to see the image ? if the snippet is not working

Comment: ok, I have updated the snippet so you can see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of HTML/css mistakes here like className is from javascript, css uses class. I added image placeholders and I just got rid of most styles and instead used flexbox for positioning.

Then the overlay should have position absolute and here it is exactly over the first image.

You can change the overlay positioning for proof, but with your overlay image it will have a hole in the middle to show

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/fff666/000000">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry, forgot to mention I'm currently working on react, that's why its className, but its basically the same

Comment: Oh whoops I'm a fool. I went Angular so not super familiar with react stuff

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. Sorry if I didn't clear things up on the question. I have updated it now. I saw your snippet, but It's only centered horizontally, I also need to to be centered vertically. Also need to hide the extra image from the overlay image. You can see what I mean on the updated snippet. Thank you, hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including a snippet, makes things easier.

So based on your comments on my previous answer, I just recreated this in a much easier way. This is assuming you have access to the CSS and that the card is a fixed width of 500x500.

Basically I just made one image container holding the "overlay" image, and then set the background of this container to the other image.

```css
.birthday-card {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://kb4images.com/images/picture/37509081-picture.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.birthday-card img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="birthday-card">
  <img src="http://makephotogreetings.com/upload/1456330147Happy%20Birthday%20Frame%20With%20Cup%20Cake%20and%20Your%20Photo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! The birthday card is not fixed btw, it's a bit dynamic on the program. but its always gonna be on top, and one image on the back. I just display the pure css and html here